# Symfony - multiple instances of bundle and multiple configs

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

In my project I need two instances of the same bundle - in this particular case it's `SonataMediaBundle`.

One instance is for one database and second one is for another database. The problem is, the sonata `config` lives under the same key `sonata_media` and there is no way to split this.

Should I override the Configuration file of `SonataMediaBundle` or there is more proper way to do this?

@edit: Tthis two bundles are in different entity managers

Comment: Do you have using multiple entity managers? see this doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: yes, this two bundles are in different entity managers, I will edit my post

Comment: hm.. first on mind, but not quite good - create new Kernel file, e.g. ApplicationKernel an register bundle there, than create it own config.